# Ranking from which week are used to decide who qualifies for ATP/WTA finals?

Tags: tennis, tournaments, ranking, atp, wta

I know that [race rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Race), i.e. points only from this calendar year, are used to decide players at year end ATP/WTA championships.

My question is whether the rankings just one week before the finals are taken into consideration, or whether the decision is made sooner.

For example, this year in [WTA tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_WTA_Tour) Kremlin Cup in Moscow and Luxembourg Open in Kockelscheuer will be played during the week before the [WTA Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_WTA_Finals). Can the points from these tournaments influence who will be contenders at the year end championships?

The situation in [ATP Tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_ATP_World_Tour) is a bit different (at least this year) since no tournaments are scheduled during the last week before the [ATP World Tour Finals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_ATP_World_Tour_Finals).
Similarly, before [WTA Elite Trophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Elite_Trophy) there will be one week gap (since no players will play at both at WTA Finals and WTA Elite Trophy). But we can still ask the same question - which tournaments will be relevant for the decision who qualifies for these year-end tournaments.

Comment: According to the WTA, points earned in Luxembourg Open will not be considered for WTA Finals & WTA Elite Trophy entry. Source: http://www.vavel.com/en-us/tennis-usa/549228-bgl-bnp-paribas-luxembourg-open-will-not-count-towards-final-road-to-singapore-standings.html Kremlin Cup will be considered though

Comment: Thanks for the response @KharoBangdo According to [this article on the WTA website](http://www.wtafinals.com/article/a-numbers-game-inside-look-at-the-road-to-singapore-leaderboard/5045390), Luxembourg Open will be counted for WTA Eliter Trophy but not for WTA Finals: *"The Road To Singapore leaderboard follows the same ranking guidelines as the WTA Rankings for singles, with one exception. Points earned from Luxembourg, an International event the week of October 19, will not factor in due to the fact that the Luxembourg final falls on a Sunday....*

Comment: *...The points will however, affect each player's ranking and qualification chances for the WTA Elite Trophy Zhuhai."* Still it would be nice to have some kind of more official source. (Is there something about this in ATP/WTA rulebook?)

Answer (score 3):

The week before is considered. For both the WTA and ATP Tours, every tournament - down to the very final week/tournament of the season - and all rankings points earned, are taken into consideration to determine who the selected players are, and thus who will be selected to play in the WTA Finals/World Tour Finals.